# Why does Symfony EventDispatcher use arbitrary names for events instead of class-based propagation?

Tags: design-patterns, symfony, observer-pattern, event-dispatching

I'm looking to implement Observer Pattern into my app (not php, that's why not using Symfony's component).

I found it strange though that the component is not using classes to propagate or listen to events since that would allow listening on whole tree of events using inheritance.

I can't see the single advantage of using name-based listeners, would you help me with my pondering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symfony2, in my opinion, favors cohesion over coupling and that's why they use this pattern ([Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)).

From [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html):

> Objected Oriented code has gone a long way to ensuring code
>   extensibility. By creating classes that have well defined
>   responsibilities, your code becomes more flexible and a developer can
>   extend them with subclasses to modify their behaviors. But if he wants
>   to share his changes with other developers who have also made their
>   own subclasses, code inheritance is no longer the answer.
>
> Consider the
>   real-world example where you want to provide a plugin system for your
>   project. A plugin should be able to add methods, or do something
>   before or after a method is executed, without interfering with other
>   plugins. This is not an easy problem to solve with single inheritance,
>   and multiple inheritance (were it possible with PHP) has its own
>   drawbacks.
>
> The Symfony2 Event Dispatcher component implements the
>   Mediator pattern in a simple and effective way to make all these
>   things possible and to make your projects truly extensible.